# tikzmark shadow around box

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

I have drawn a rounded box around my equations using this code :

```
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\hfsetbordercolor{green}
\begin{equation}
\tikzmarkin{g}(0.4,-0.5)(-0.2,0.75)r = \frac{n \sum xy - \sum x \sum y}  {\sqrt{[n \sum x^2 - (\sum x)^2][n \sum y^2 - (\sum y)^2]}}\tikzmarkend{g}
\end{equation}
```

I'm wandering how I can add a grey shadow around the outline of the box ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `\tikzmarkin` is not a command defined by either the `tikzmark` libary or TikZ itself, can you add a complete example? Edit: OK, I see it's defined by `hf-tikz`, but still, an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would have been preferable.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution. This one uses `tcolorbox` instead of `mdframed`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{colback=yellow!20!white,colframe=blue!50!black,
    highlight math style={enhanced, drop shadow}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath{r=\frac{n \sum xy - \sum x \sum y}  {\sqrt{[n \sum x^2 - (\sum x)^2][n \sum y^2 - (\sum y)^2]}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not rounded box ... but for starting point should serve the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{fancybox}
    \usepackage{empheq}


\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}% just to show only equation
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
    \definecolor{shadowcolor}{rgb}{0,.5,.5}
    \setlength\shadowsize{2pt}

    \begin{preview}
\begin{empheq}[box=\shadowbox*]{gather}
E = mc^2
    \end{empheq}
    \end{preview}
    \end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

When you provide MWE or what you try so far, I will try to adopt this answer to your wish.